# sending a file with another data using axios with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a file "image" with another post parameters using axios with react library, this is my original code which works very well sending one image or a file to the server.. in the server i'm using multer library to save the images:

```
submitFormImagen(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const token = localStorage.getItem('auth-token');
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('myImage',this.state.file);

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'auth-token': token
            }
        };
        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/user/upload",formData,config)
            .then((response) => {
                alert("The file is successfully uploaded");
                console.log(response)
                this.setState({imagen: response.data.imagen})
            }).catch((error) => {
        });
    }
```

in this case: formData is necessary to multer library can save the image; this is my code from the server:

```
router.post('/upload', verificarToken, async function(req,res){
    //imagen nombre: req.file.filename
    console.log(req.body)
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
    const _id = req.user._id
    upload (req, res, async function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Ocurrio un error al subir el archivo.");
        }

        const rutaimagen = url + "/uploads/" +req.file.filename

        //Actualizar Imagen del usuario:
       await User.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, {
            imagen: rutaimagen
        });
        //res.end("Archivo subido correctamente!");
        res.json({imagen: rutaimagen})
    });

  });
```

basically that's it now i'm trying to capture the request body to try to update the user image and his name and email..
this update does not work:

```
submitFormImagen(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const token = localStorage.getItem('auth-token');
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('myImage',this.state.file);
        var post = {
            myImage: this.state.file,
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email
        }
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'auth-token': token
            }
        };
        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/user/upload",post,config)
            .then((response) => {
                alert("The file is successfully uploaded");
                console.log(response)
                this.setState({imagen: response.data.imagen})
            }).catch((error) => {
        });
    }
```

Also I tryed:

```
 formData.append('myImage',this.state.file);
    var post = {
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email
    }
    formData.append('anotherdata',post);
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'auth-token': token
        }
    };
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/user/upload",formData,config)
...
```

and now i'm trying to get the value of "anotherdata" inside the upload function from the server which is inside the upload route.. but I got:

```
[Object: null prototype] { anotherdata: '[object Object]' }
```

this is the code of the server:

```
router.post('/upload', verificarToken, async function(req,res){
    //imagen nombre: req.file.filename

    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
    const _id = req.user._id
    upload (req, res, async function(err) {
        console.log(req.body) //<*********
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Ocurrio un error al subir el archivo.");
        }
```

Comment: >> formData.append('anotherdata',post);
can you try ormData.append('anotherdata',JSON.stringtify(post) );

Comment: Hi Truong it works! is JSON.stringify(). I saw the req body on the console and I got: [Object: null prototype] {
  anotherdata: '{"name":"test name","email":"testemail@test.com"}' } however I only need "anotherdata" object.. I could acces to it of this way: const data = req.body.anotherdata but if I try to access now to some property of the object like this way: console.log(data.name) it say undefined.. if i print console.log(data) it has not no tiene apariencia de un json. es un json en un string {"name":"test name","email":"testemail@test.com"}.. what could I do? thanks..

Comment: I uploaded this two pictures where we can see the problem when i try to access to some value of anotherdata: https://imgur.com/a/3QBp6Yb https://imgur.com/a/dNzdmeY

Comment: I fixed it using JSON.parse() this function was passed to the req.body.anotherdata staying this way: const data = JSON.parse(req.body.anotherdata) finally i could access to a property of the object.. console.log(data.name) https://imgur.com/a/y4DznUT

Comment: exactly. JSON.stringify will be encode json to string so you need to use JSON.parse for decode json string  to Json object.